# Auth::user(); doesn't returns users, using passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have situation about returning users from DB. In my controller I am trying it like below:

**UPDATED:**

NOTE: for clear misunderstanding. Actually I am logged in as a user. No problem with that part. But it looks like auth:: doesn't understand that and when I try to retrieve users. it's redirecting me to login's endpoint...

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function getUser(){

        $users = Auth::user();
        dd($users);
    }
}
```

And about the api route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::post("logout", "Api\AuthController@logout");

    /* User */
    Route::get('/user', 'Api\UsersController@getUser');

});


Route::group(["prefix" => "v1"], function(){

    /* Auth */
    Route::post("login", "Api\AuthController@login")->name("login");
    Route::post("register", "Api\AuthController@register");

});
```

Here is the thing. If I use my UserController route outside the middleware:api then endpoint is returns null. And if use it inside the middleware it redirects me to my login's endpoint. Because of the `"->name('login')"`

In the end I can't return the users. Additionally this is what config/auth looks like.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

By the way before asked. I tried to change guard's web to api but nothing is changed.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Is there anyone have better understanding on this situation. How can I return users with using passport? Do I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is with the request header. Only a logged in user can call `/api/user` endpoint with an `access_token` in the request header.

Request header will have this pair

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1..........
```

Nothing to do in laravel part, as it's working as expected.

Comment: oh, sorry I have that providers. it's laravel's defaults... :) I  just didn't think I should put that in question too...

Comment: I see. Can you please, post your get request details. As `/user` is under auth middleware, you need to be authenticated first and use authentication key in the subsequest requests.

Comment: okay, I updated it at the bottom of the question. it's laravel's default. And I am not very sure how to customize it or do I need to ?

Comment: `class Authenticate` is a default middleware for laravel framework and you shouldn't update it. If you need some other middleware you can create and put in `app/Http/Middleware`

Comment: then, how can I fix this situation? Any idea for that? Why it's redirecting me to login's endpoint? this is really troublesome...

Comment: it's redirecting to login because you are not logged in/authenticated. You need to login first by a POST request to `/oauth/token` then you can use the received token to call `/user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195898/discussion-between-parabellum-and-minhazur).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Passport. Let's read and make your step same in document: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

From your API request, need to pass the access_token to backend.

Hoping you can resolve that issue!

Comment: first, i think this should be a comment not an answer. And if you be more clear about "pass the access_token to backend." it would be good.

Comment: The first, please try use passport same in Laravel document. They said very clearly and put your access_token in header of api request.